# Using Sqlite to query a database I have a columns with spaces and special characters

Tags: python, sqlite

Whilst trying to query a column which has spaces and commas, I tried using "Element,_Middle_or_High" using double quotes, and underscores, yet I am unable to get the result I want, but rather get:

*sqlite3.OperationalError) near "or": syntax error*
*[SQL: SELECT Elementary, Middle, or High School AVG(Safety_Score) as Average_Safety_Score FROM chicago_public_schools_data ORDER BY Average_Safety_Score;]*

Tried double quotes and doesn't work.

Comment: *Tried double quotes and doesn't work*. Do not just say you tried, but please show how you tried. Double quotes are the way to go and should work if correctly used...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks found a solution, by reading this [link](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/using-sqlite/9781449394592/ch04s03.html). This involved using backticks (MySQL) instead of using double quotes which work for PostgreSQL and Oracle